# VS Code Java compiler can not recognize Lombok code generation

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, lombok

I have an issue with my editor vscode. Recently we decided to use Lombok, but the problem that vscode did not recognize methods generated by Lombok. I did install the Lombok extension, but maven compiler running well.

My settings.json:

"java.jdt.ls.lombokSupport.enabled": true,
"java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "-javaagent:/..../lombok.jar",

My pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n804N.png)

Please see description

Comment: Further comment: VS Code compiler error in the line of var user = User.builder(): 

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method builder()

Comment: I don't know if this will help or not: [*Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/)

Comment: VSCode uses eclipse as language server, and eclipse's support for lombok is stellar. We maintain it ourselves. So there shouldn't be an issue here; did you follow [these instructions](https://projectlombok.org/setup/vscode)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @rzwitserloot I used exactly the instructions, but I still have the vscode compiler error like this: "cannot find symbol:  method builder()" in my code **var user = User.builder();**. But Lombok generates methods as well. The problem is the vscode onthefly compiler...